# Finding the number of distinct real roots of $(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3=0$ for $a$, $b$, $c$ distinct real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

This question was asked to me by a junior and I was unable to solve it. So, I am asking for help here.

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be distinct real numbers. Then the number of distinct real roots of the equation $(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3=0$ is
>
> (i) $1\quad$ (ii) $2\quad$ (iii) $3$

Answer

> (i)  $1$

Well , in the question field is not given but even if it was given i don't know how to approach this particular question.

I have studied solution of cubic equations 4 years back but I am asking if it's possible to solve it without use results from solutions of cubic equation, as they are very rarely used and hence I don't remember them.

Thanks!!

Comment: None of the answers seem consistent with the pre-calculus tag.  Are you talking about a *junior* in high school, who never studied Calculus?  I can think of only 1 pre-calculus approach.  Unfortunately, I just tried it, and the math got ugly fast.  **This approach may lead nowhere - you've been warned.** ...see next comment.

Comment: Multiply the equation out completely, and obtain a 3rd degree polynomial.  Assume that the real root is $r$.  Perform polynomial long division with the divisor of $(x-r).$  Obtain a quotient in the form of $Ax^2 + Bx + C.$  Prove that in the resulting quadratic, $B^2 < 4AC.$ ... Told you it was ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f={(x-a)^3}+{(x-b)^3}+{(x-c)^3}$$

$$f'={3(x-a)^2}+{3(x-b)^2}+{3(x-c)^2}\ge0$$

This shows that the graph is non decreasing. So $f$ crosses x-axis only once

Note that the equality occurs when $x=a=b=c=t$

Comment: But how was this solved by the *junior*, consistent with the pre-calculus tag?

Answer (score 1):

Since each of the $(x-a)^3$, $(x-b)^3$, $(x-c)^3$ is always increasing, then their sum is as well. Now considering the graph of function $y=(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3$, it's always increasing, so it crosses the x-axis only once, so only 1 real root.

All the above can be formulated more rigorously using derivatives.

Comment: But how was this solved by the *junior*, consistent with the pre-calculus tag?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The left hand side $(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3$ is a sum of 3 terms, each is equivalent (up to a shift in $x$)  to $x^3$ which is familiar to pre-calculus to have only one zero. Thus the sum of the 3 can only produce "elongation"  along the $y$ axis but cannot produce more zeros.

Comment: +1 Very nice reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

$x^3$ is an increasing function, because $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=(a-b)\left(\left((a+\frac b2\right)^2+\frac {3b^2}{4}\right)$$always has the sign of $(a-b)$. (Note this is what we mean by strictly increasing, and is equivalent to any other definition). Note that the second term is a sum of squares which is always non-negative and is only zero when $a=b=0$.

The factorisation and completing the square are both elementary, pre-calculus, operations - though it is likely a junior would know $x^3$ is increasing from graphing it even without a formal proof.

So the function given is the sum of three increasing functions and is itself increasing - this is elementary. To pull out material from comments and extend it, if $f(x)=x^3$ is increasing so is $g(x)=(x-a)^3$ which is simply the original function translated.

Also if $f,g,h$ are three increasing functions and $y\gt x$ then $f(y)\gt f(x), g(y)\gt g(x), h(y)\gt h(x)$ and the sum of the three larger elements of each inequality is greater than the sum of the three smaller elements.

It can therefore have at most one zero. Note that if $f(x)$ is increasing and $f(x)=0$ then if $y\lt x$ then $f(y)\lt f(x)=0$ and similarly for $y\gt x$, so $x$ is the only zero. $f(x)=e^x$ is an increasing function with no zeros, so we are not yet done (except to note that only one of the given answers is possible). To show that there is a zero we need to go further.

A cubic with real coefficients always has at least one zero (also well known pre calculus). Really you need properties of the real numbers and continuity for this [it isn't true for the rationals, for example] but again it can be known before it can be rigorously proved.

Here you can easily show (unless $a=b=c=0$) that the function is negative for $x=-2\left(|a|+|b|+|c|\right)$ and positive for $x=2\left(|a|+|b|+|c|\right)$ - for these values the function clearly has the same sign as $x$. Then the intermediate value theorem shows there is a zero. But pre-calculus this may be non-rigorous intuition. For the additional case you just have $3x^3=0$ which has the zero $x=0$.

---

Note that this analysis uses only the facts that (a) we are dealing with an increasing function; and (b) a cubic with real coefficients has at least one real root. The values of $a,b,c$ are irrelevant and I have not tried to locate the root with any accuracy, nor explored in any detail where the actual function given is positive or negative. To solve the problem set only requires a crude analysis.

Comment: "If $f(x)=x^3$ is increasing so is $g(x)=(x−a)^3$ which is simply 
the original function translated." Nice translation argument,
which had escaped me.  I definitely agree, and I have deleted all
my comments.  Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: @user2661923 I'll delete my irrelevant comments, but just to say, fighting through this kind of thing is how we learn most effectively, and persisting with your real question is a great learning strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3$ and $a>b>c.$

Thus, $$f(a)=(a-b)^3+(a-c)^3>0,$$ $$f(c)=(c-a)^3+(c-b)^3<0$$ and
$$f'(x)=3\sum_{cyc}(x-a)^2>0,$$ which says that our equation has an unique real root and this root is placed on $(c,a).$

Comment: Interesting approach.  Is there any way that you can change or augment your answer so that the assertion is proven via only pre-calculus analysis (which would exclude using $f'(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.

As others have indicated, it is sufficient to show that $(x-a)^3$ is an increasing function.  I am going to offer a somewhat different argument.

$(x-a)^3$ can be factored into $R \times S$, where

$R = (x-a)$ and $S = (x-a)^2.$

There are two cases:

$\underline{\text{Case 1: } x < a}$.

As $x$ **decreases**, $|R|$ increases, and $S$ increases.

Therefore, as $x$ decreases, $|R \times S|$ increases.

Therefore, since in case 1, $R < 0,$ as $x$ is decreasing, 
$(R \times S)$ is **also decreasing**.

Therefore, in case 1, as $x$ **increases**,
$(R \times S)$ **also increases**.

$\underline{\text{Case 2: } x \geq a}$.

In case 2, $R$ is always non-negative.

Therefore, as $x$ **increases**, $R$ increases, and $S$  increases.

Therefore, in case 2, as $x$ **increases**,
$(R \times S)$ **also increases**.